# Join several Temp Tables with Row ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

My code:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp15') IS NOT NULL BEGIN
       drop table #Temp15
    end

SELECT * into #Temp15
   from (
select
cast(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CM3RM1.NUMBER ORDER BY INCIDENTSM1.OPEN_TIME)as int) as tempid
,INCIDENTSM1.INCIDENT_ID AS SD_NR
,INCIDENTSM1.OPEN_TIME AS SD_OP
,INCIDENTSM1.CLOSE_TIME AS SD_CL
FROM INCIDENTSM1
LEFT OUTER JOIN SCRELATIONM1 ON INCIDENTSM1.INCIDENT_ID = SCRELATIONM1.SOURCE COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
LEFT OUTER JOIN CM3RM1 ON CM3RM1.NUMBER = SCRELATIONM1.DEPEND
WHERE CM3RM1.NUMBER IN ('C45168')
)
as databases (tempid, SD_NR, SD_OP, SD_CL)

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp1') IS NOT NULL BEGIN
       drop table #Temp1
end

SELECT * into #Temp1
   from (
select
cast(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY parent_change ORDER BY number)as int) as tempid
,number as tasknr
,category as cat
,orig_date_entered as taskop
,parent_change as chgnr1
,case when (CM3TM1.status = 'closed') then CM3TM1.date_entered else NULL end as taskcl
FROM CM3TM1
WHERE parent_change IN ('C45168')
and category = 'NEU Development' 
)
as databases (tempid, tasknr, devcat, taskop, chgnr1, taskcl)

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp2') IS NOT NULL BEGIN
       drop table #Temp2
end
SELECT * into #Temp2
   from (
select
cast(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY parent_change ORDER BY number)as int) as tempid
,number as tasknr
,category as cat
,orig_date_entered as taskop
,case when (CM3TM1.status = 'closed') then CM3TM1.date_entered else NULL end as taskcl
FROM CM3TM1
WHERE parent_change IN ('C45168')
and category = 'NEU Impl. to Production' 
)
as databases (tempid, tasknr, prodcat, taskop, taskcl)

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp4') IS NOT NULL BEGIN
       drop table #Temp4
end
SELECT * into #Temp4
   from (
select distinct
 cast(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CM3RM1.NUMBER ORDER BY ACTIVITYCM3M1.datestamp)as int) as tempid
,ACTIVITYCM3M1.datestamp as CHR_T
from CM3RM1
  INNER JOIN CM3RM2
    ON CM3RM1.NUMBER = CM3RM2.NUMBER
  LEFT OUTER JOIN ACTIVITYCM3M1
    ON CM3RM1.NUMBER = ACTIVITYCM3M1.NUMBER
where ACTIVITYCM3M1.description like '%to "Change Review"%'
and CM3RM1.NUMBER IN ('C45168') 
)
as databases (tempid, CHR_T)

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp5') IS NOT NULL BEGIN
       drop table #Temp5
end
SELECT * into #Temp5
   from (
select
 cast(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CM3RM1.NUMBER ORDER BY APPROVALLOGM1.DATE)as int) as tempid
,APPROVALLOGM1.DATE as APT
from CM3RM1
  INNER JOIN CM3RM2
    ON CM3RM1.NUMBER = CM3RM2.NUMBER
 LEFT OUTER JOIN APPROVALLOGM1
    ON CM3RM1.NUMBER = APPROVALLOGM1.UNIQUE_KEY
where APPROVALLOGM1.current_phase = 'Change Review'
and APPROVALLOGM1.[group] like 'ABB Ventyx CLS SD'
and CM3RM1.NUMBER IN ('C45168') 
)
as databases (tempid, APT)

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp6') IS NOT NULL BEGIN
       drop table #Temp6
end
SELECT * into #Temp6
   from (
select
 cast(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CM3RM2.NUMBER ORDER BY APPROVALLOGM1.DATE)as int) as tempid
,APPROVALLOGM1.DATE as APT2
from CM3RM1
  INNER JOIN CM3RM2
    ON CM3RM1.NUMBER = CM3RM2.NUMBER
 LEFT OUTER JOIN APPROVALLOGM1
    ON CM3RM1.NUMBER = APPROVALLOGM1.UNIQUE_KEY
where APPROVALLOGM1.current_phase = 'Change Review'
and APPROVALLOGM1.[group] not like 'ABB Ventyx CLS SD'
and CM3RM1.NUMBER IN ('C45168') 
)
as databases (tempid, APT2)

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp7') IS NOT NULL BEGIN
       drop table #Temp7
end
SELECT * into #Temp7
   from (
select distinct
 cast(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CM3RM1.NUMBER ORDER BY ACTIVITYCM3M1.datestamp)as int) as tempid
,ACTIVITYCM3M1.datestamp as CHA_T
from CM3RM1
  INNER JOIN CM3RM2
    ON CM3RM1.NUMBER = CM3RM2.NUMBER
  LEFT OUTER JOIN ACTIVITYCM3M1
    ON CM3RM1.NUMBER = ACTIVITYCM3M1.NUMBER
where ACTIVITYCM3M1.description like '%Review" to "Change Assessment%'
and CM3RM1.NUMBER IN ('C45168') 
)
as databases (tempid, CHA_T)

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp3') IS NOT NULL BEGIN
       drop table #Temp3
end

SELECT * into #Temp3
   from (
select
cast(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CM3RM1.NUMBER ORDER BY CM3RM1.orig_date_entered)as int) as tempid
,CM3RM1.NUMBER as chgnr
,CM3RM1.orig_date_entered AS CH_OP
,CM3RM2.AFFECTED_ITEM AS Service
FROM CM3RM1
INNER JOIN CM3RM2 ON CM3RM1.NUMBER = CM3RM2.NUMBER
LEFT OUTER JOIN SCRELATIONM1 ON CM3RM1.NUMBER = SCRELATIONM1.DEPEND COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
WHERE CM3RM1.NUMBER IN ('C45168')
)
as databases (tempid, chgnr, CH_OP, Service)

select
 isnull(#Temp15.SD_NR, '') as [Interaction ID]
,isnull(LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, #Temp15.SD_OP, 120), 16), '') as [Interaction Opened]
,isnull(LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, #Temp3.CH_OP, 120), 16), '') as [Escalated Ticket ]
,isnull(#Temp3.chgnr, '') as [Change ID]
,isnull(LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, #Temp4.CHR_T, 120), 16), '') as [Change Review Phase Start]
,isnull(LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, #Temp5.APT, 120), 16), '') as [Approver 1]
,isnull(LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, #Temp6.APT2, 120), 16), '') as [Approver 2]
,isnull(LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, #Temp7.CHA_T, 120), 16), '') as [Change Assessment & Planning Phase Start]
from #Temp3 full join #Temp1 on #Temp3.tempid = #Temp1.tempid
full join #Temp2 on #Temp3.tempid = #Temp2.tempid
full join #Temp4 on #Temp3.tempid = #Temp4.tempid
full join #Temp5 on #Temp3.tempid = #Temp5.tempid
full join #Temp6 on #Temp3.tempid = #Temp6.tempid
full join #Temp7 on #Temp3.tempid = #Temp7.tempid
full join #Temp15 on #Temp3.tempid = #Temp15.tempid
```

I want to join several Temp Tables in a such way that it's always product maximum number of rows according to which table have max records. With code as above it produces unexpected shifting of data.
Please see how it looks like on the screen shot:

http://snag.gy/TNXEH.jpg

Left join can't be used because there is no rule which column has the most rows.
One certain column ([Change ID] in that example) is never null and always has one row.
Others can be empty sometimes.

I've tried to reproduce the problem with a different query, as it was advised. When I run two temp tables separately with a code as below:

```
IF (SELECT object_id('TempDB..#t3')) IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #t3
END

create table #t3 (id int, tasknr varchar(50), cat varchar(50), taskop datetime, taskcl datetime)
insert into #t3 (id, tasknr, cat, taskop, taskcl)

select
cast(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY parent_change ORDER BY number)as int) as id
,number as tasknr
,category as cat
,orig_date_entered as taskop
,case when (CM3TM1.status = 'closed') then CM3TM1.date_entered else NULL end as taskcl
FROM CM3TM1
WHERE parent_change IN ('C45168')
and category = 'NEU Development' 

select * from #t3

IF (SELECT object_id('TempDB..#t4')) IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #t4
END

create table #t4 (id int, tasknr varchar(50), cat varchar(50), taskop datetime, taskcl datetime)
insert into #t4 (id, tasknr, cat, taskop, taskcl)

select
cast(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY parent_change ORDER BY number)as int) as id
,number as tasknr
,category as cat
,orig_date_entered as taskop
,case when (CM3TM1.status = 'closed') then CM3TM1.date_entered else NULL end as taskcl
FROM CM3TM1
WHERE parent_change IN ('C45168')
and category = 'NEU Impl. to Production' 

select * from #t4
```

it looks correct but when I'm  running it inside the query as below:

```
IF (SELECT object_id('TempDB..#t1')) IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #t1
END

create table #t1 (id int, chgnr varchar(50))
insert into #t1 (id, chgnr)

select
cast(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY number ORDER BY number)as int) as id
,number as chgnr
FROM CM3RM1
WHERE number IN ('C45168')

IF (SELECT object_id('TempDB..#t2')) IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #t2
END

create table #t2 (id int, SD_NR varchar(50), SD_OP datetime, SD_CL datetime)
insert into #t2 (id, SD_NR, SD_OP, SD_CL)

select
cast(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CM3RM1.NUMBER ORDER BY INCIDENTSM1.OPEN_TIME)as int) as id
,INCIDENTSM1.INCIDENT_ID AS SD_NR
,INCIDENTSM1.OPEN_TIME AS SD_OP
,INCIDENTSM1.CLOSE_TIME AS SD_CL
FROM INCIDENTSM1
LEFT OUTER JOIN SCRELATIONM1 ON INCIDENTSM1.INCIDENT_ID = SCRELATIONM1.SOURCE COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
LEFT OUTER JOIN CM3RM1 ON CM3RM1.NUMBER = SCRELATIONM1.DEPEND
WHERE CM3RM1.NUMBER IN ('C45168')

IF (SELECT object_id('TempDB..#t3')) IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #t3
END

create table #t3 (id int, tasknr varchar(50), cat varchar(50), taskop datetime, taskcl datetime)
insert into #t3 (id, tasknr, cat, taskop, taskcl)

select
cast(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY parent_change ORDER BY number)as int) as id
,number as tasknr
,category as cat
,orig_date_entered as taskop
,case when (CM3TM1.status = 'closed') then CM3TM1.date_entered else NULL end as taskcl
FROM CM3TM1
WHERE parent_change IN ('C45168')
and category = 'NEU Development' 

IF (SELECT object_id('TempDB..#t4')) IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #t4
END

create table #t4 (id int, tasknr varchar(50), cat varchar(50), taskop datetime, taskcl datetime)
insert into #t4 (id, tasknr, cat, taskop, taskcl)

select
cast(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY parent_change ORDER BY number)as int) as id
,number as tasknr
,category as cat
,orig_date_entered as taskop
,case when (CM3TM1.status = 'closed') then CM3TM1.date_entered else NULL end as taskcl
FROM CM3TM1
WHERE parent_change IN ('C45168')
and category = 'NEU Impl. to Production' 

select #t2.SD_NR, #t2.SD_OP, #t1.chgnr, #t3.tasknr devtasknr, #t3.taskop devtaskop, #t4.tasknr prodtasknr, #t4.taskop prodtaskop
from #t1
full join #t2 on #t2.id = #t1.id
full join #t3 on #t3.id = #t1.id
full join #t4 on #t4.id = #t1.id
```

it looks not correct, please see the comparision here: http://snag.gy/N1HeI.jpg

Why T85341 and T85179 are not at the same row when both of them got id = 2 ?

Could anyone please let me know how to solve this?

Comment: You have tagged the question MySQL, yet you are using SQL Server syntax.  Please tag the question appropriately.

Comment: `With code as above it produces unexpected shifting of data` - it is not shifting, just the `ISNULL` is doing it's job. And, `FULL OUTER JOIN` will have as many rows as the one with maximum records, so you right about that.

Comment: From my experiences, without ISNULL it looks like on the screen shot here: http://snag.gy/YEDg9.jpg and this is quite ok but it's still not correct.